# Gnome-Panel - in which folder are the icons (to launch apps) located like of firefox and of thunderbird?

Tags: gnome, .desktop, gnome-panel, desktop-icons

Here is Gnome Windows manager with Desktop-Panel, where to the left side is the sidebar with icons.
Yes, there are icons, and I want to edit these icons for to launch different versions of firefox or of thunderbird.

Where can I edit these icons with text-editor ? Which directory contains these icons ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean /usr/share/applications/ directory .desktop files?

Comment: Those icons r from the icon theme.. First determine which Icon theme is currently in use. Then go to that icon theme directory n search with keywords..

Comment: If you have not configured any icon theme.. You may search in `/usr/share/icons/$THMENAME`

Comment: @UnKNOWn - you mean icon theme like "Papirus" ? Have I then to look in /usr/share/icons/Papirus ?

Comment: Yes of your current icon theme is Papirus..look into that folder and serach for icon names you r looking for.. There may be few icons with same name in diffefent sizes..